# What scripture describes humans as being morally superior to angels?

Tags: myth-identification, interpretation, angels

At the climax of *Fate/stay night*'s Heaven's Feel route, the main antagonist, Kirei Kotomine [refers to a religious scripture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wLHKS6EOko&t=400s) that says humans are morally superior to angels because humans can choose between committing good or evil acts. Is there such a scripture that mentions this?

Comment: He's probably referencing a certain [passage](http://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.88b.7-89a.2?lang=en) of the [Talmudic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmud) tractate [Sabbath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shabbat_(Talmud)), where the Jewish Prophet and Law-Giver Moses ascends to Heaven to take the Torah down to earth, from the Angels, arguing that it's much better suited for humans, since its commandments are somewhat superfluous for heavenly beings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the video:

“A certain scripture mentions that humans are superior beings to angels."

The character misunderstands the scriptural reference - it refers to Jesus, not to humans generally. (Though humans who find the 'Narrow Path' will be "given a new name" - Rev. 2:17, and others.)

> **Hebrews 1:5 (KJV)**
>
> (Commentaries can be found here:
>   https://www.studylight.org/commentary/hebrews/1-4.html )
>
> 2 Hath in these last days spoken unto us **by his Son**, whom he hath
>   appointed heir of all things, by whom also he made the worlds;
>
> 3 Who being the brightness of his glory, and the express image of his
>   person, and upholding all things by the word of his power, **when he
>   had by himself purged our sins**, sat down on the right hand of the
>   Majesty on high:
>
> 4 **Being made so much better than the angels, as he hath by
>   inheritance obtained a more excellent name than they.**
>
> 5 For unto which of the angels said he at any time, Thou art my Son,
>   this day have I begotten thee? And again, I will be to him a Father,
>   and he shall be to me a Son?
>
> **Philippians 2:6-11 (KJV)**
>
> 6 Who, being in the form of God, thought it not robbery to be equal
>   with God:
>
> 7 But made himself of no reputation, and took upon him the form of a
>   servant, and was made in the likeness of men:
>
> 8 And being found in fashion as a man, he humbled himself, and became
>   obedient unto death, even the death of the cross.
>
> 9 Wherefore God also hath highly exalted him, and given him a name
>   which is above every name:
>
> 10 That at the name of Jesus every knee should bow, of things in
>   heaven, and things in earth, and things under the earth;
>
> 11 And that every tongue should confess that Jesus Christ is Lord, to
>   the glory of God the Father.